# Gulp: Why "jshint" does not run on file change?

Tags: gulp

Here are the relevant parts of my `gulpfile.js`:

```
var paths = {
  sass:    ['./www/**/*.scss'],
  scripts: ['./www/**/*.js', '!./www/lib/**/*.js']
};

gulp.task('jshint', function(done) {
  console.log('Running jshint');
  gulp.src(paths.scripts)
      .pipe(jshint())
      .pipe(jshint.reporter('default'))
      .on('end', done);
});

gulp.task('scripts', function(done) {
  console.log('Running scripts');
  gulp.src(paths.scripts)
      .pipe(concat('chessmate.js'))
      .pipe(gulp.dest('./www/'))
      .on('end', done);
});

gulp.task('sass', function(done) {
  gulp.src('./www/ionic.app.scss')
      .pipe(sass({
        errLogToConsole: true,
        includePaths: []
      }))
      .pipe(concat('chessmate.css'))
      .pipe(gulp.dest('./www/'))
      .on('end', done);
});

gulp.task('watch', function() {
  gulp.watch(paths.sass, ['sass']);
  gulp.watch(paths.scripts, ['jshint', 'scripts']);
});

gulp.task('default', ['jshint', 'scripts', 'sass', 'watch']);
```

When I run `gulp`, both `jshint` and `scripts` are run:

```
[gulp] Using gulpfile /Users/mishamoroshko/ChessMate/gulpfile.js
[gulp] Starting 'jshint'...
Running jshint
[gulp] Starting 'scripts'...
Running scripts
[gulp] Starting 'sass'...
[gulp] Starting 'watch'...
[gulp] Finished 'watch' after 93 ms
```

But, if then I update `app.js`, only `scripts` is run:

```
[gulp] Starting 'scripts'...
Running scripts
[gulp] Finished 'scripts' after 396 ms
```

Why `jshint` doesn't run?

Comment: Perhaps if your first jshint fails with an hint error (due to bad js) it does not emit 'end'. Since you signal done only on 'end' gulp thinks the first jshint task is still running on consecutive changes and will nit run it again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently, changing from this style:

```
gulp.task('taskname', function(done) {
  [do stuff].on('end', done);
});
```

to this one:

```
gulp.task('taskname', function() {
  return [do stuff];
});
```

solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like it should run automatically to me, but since it's not, one thing you could try is adding the `jshint` task as a dependency for the `scripts` task like so:

```
gulp.task('scripts', ['jshint'], function(done) {
  console.log('Running scripts');
  gulp.src(paths.scripts)
      .pipe(concat('chessmate.js'))
      .pipe(gulp.dest('./www/'))
      .on('end', done);
});
```

Hope that helps. If that works for you, you should also be able to remove `jshint` from your `watch` task:

```
gulp.task('watch', function() {
  gulp.watch(paths.sass, ['sass']);
  gulp.watch(paths.scripts, [ /*'jshint',*/ 'scripts']);
});
```